# Measure to count values in two columns where they both exist in same record

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a measure that will count the number of rows in a table where a pair of values exists in two columns. I am looking for the number of rows where 611 AND 612 both exist (in either order). An example of what I mean is like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm3th.png)

I started by trying something like below, but it counts all occurrences of 611 and 612 rather than where they are in the same record.

```
Measure = 
(CALCULATE(
COUNTA('Table'[ Company]),
'Table'[Code1]
    IN { "611" }) 
+   CALCULATE(
COUNTA('Table'[ Company]), 
'Table'[Code2] 
        IN {"612" })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Measure = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Table'[Company]),
    ('Table'[Code1] = 611 && 'Table'[Code2] = 612) ||
    ('Table'[Code1] = 612 && 'Table'[Code2] = 611)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. Works a treat. Basic DAX operators, but you have to learn sometime!!